# Django search form for filtering

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am currently doing a search using forms
This is my views.py

```py
class HomeView(generic.ListView):
    model = Consultant
    template_name = 'sogeti/home.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query:
            return Consultant.objects.filter(
                Q(first_name__icontains=query) |
                Q(last_name__icontains=query) |
                Q(group__title_techGroup__contains=query) |
                Q(practices__title_practice__contains=query)
            )
        else:
            return Consultant.objects.all()
```

and this is my home.html

```html
<form action="" method="get" class="form-inline">
                <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Enter Keyword" value="{{ request.GET.q }}" class="form-control">
                <select name="filter" class="form-control">
                    <option value="all">All</option>
                    <option value="people">People</option>
                    <option value="certification">Certification</option>
                    <option value="skillset">Skillset</option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default">
            </form>

<ol style="padding-left: 15px">
                    {% for consultant in object_list %}
                        <li>
                            <a href="{% url 'sogeti:detail' consultant.id %}">{{ consultant.first_name }}, {{ consultant.last_name }}</a> </br>
                            Technology Group: {{ consultant.group }} </br>
                            Primary Practice: {{ consultant.practices }}
                            <hr style="margin-left: 0">
                        </li> 
                    {% endfor %}
                </ol>
```

My first problem is that when it tries to search something (Eg: bla) that is not in my database, it returns a blank screen. Nothing at all. Tried searching but could not get any answers.

My second problem is how am I able to specify my search using HTML select and options to filter. As you can see from my home.html I have the  tag with option value but no idea how to utilize it for Django.

[image: filter search]

Thank you so much for your help! Really appriciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

About first issue, you actually can double check the `object_list` before iterate over it, e.g:

```
{% if object_list %}
    <ul>
        {% for item in object_list %}
            <p>{{item.value}}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>Empty!</p>
{% endif %}
```

If you're unable to search, then double check your query by using some tools like `django-debug-toolbar` to take a look at the queries.

About the second question, I recommend you to use Django Form instead, like so:
Create `forms.py`:

```
from django.forms import Form, ChoiceField, CharField


class FilterForm(Form):
    FILTER_CHOICES = (
        ('all', 'All'),
        ('people', 'People'),
        ('certification', 'Certification'),
        ('skillset', 'Skillset'),
    )
    search = CharField(required=False)
    filter_field = ChoiceField(choices=FILTER_CHOICES)
```

Then your view (`views.py`):

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Consultant
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('search')
        filter_field = self.request.GET.get('filter_field')
        # Do your filter and search here

        return Consultant.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['form'] = FilterForm(initial={
            'search': self.request.GET.get('search', ''),
            'filter_field': self.request.GET.get('filter_field', ''),
        })

        return context
```

and finally your template (`templates/home.html`):

```
<form class="row">
    {{ form.search }}
    {{ form.filter_field }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search">
</form>
```

Hope that would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

For the first issue, if there is nothing in the database it is returning an empty queryset so if you include

```
{% if object_list %}
    do stuff
{% else %}
    No results match your search
{% endif %}
```

For the second it depends on what you're trying to do, but let's suppose it is a 
specific field you're searching.

```
search_choice = self.request.GET.get('filter')
choice_query = Q(search_field=search_choice)
```

Then simply add this to your query

Comment: Python objects have a truth value by themselves and the truth value of an empty queryset is `False`, so you can just test for `{% if object_list %}`, which will be faster.

Comment: Edited following Bruno's comment

Comment: I added a list to my html snippet above. For the first solution you provided, where do I add `{% if object_list %}`. Also for the second do I put `if choice_query == "people" return ...` after `if query:`?

Comment: @HenryM I edited my home.html above. I tried using your solution for the first problem but I have an error saying "Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['sogeti/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']". I also tried using `{% if consultant in object_list %}` This works but it just displayed "No results match your search"

Comment: That error is to do with the URL you're putting into your template, probably. You'll have to show you new code

Answer (score 1):

views.py

```
class HomeView(generic.ListView):
    model = Consultant
    template_name = 'sogeti/home.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        q = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if q:
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                Q(first_name__icontains=q) |
                Q(last_name__icontains=q) |
                Q(group__title_techGroup__contains=q) |
                Q(practices__title_practice__contains=q)
            )
        filter = self.request.GET.get('filter')
        if filter == 'people':
            pass
        elif filter == '...':
            # do sth
        return queryset
```

html

```
<form action="" method="get" class="form-inline">
    <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Enter Keyword" value="{{ request.GET.q }}" class="form-control">
    <select name="filter" class="form-control">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        {% if request.GET.filter == 'people' %}
          <option value="people" selected>People</option>
        {% else %}
          <option value="people">People</option>
        {% endif %}
        {% if request.GET.filter == 'certification' %}
          <option value="certification" selected>Certification</option>
        {% else %}
          <option value="certification">Certification</option>
        {% endif %}
        {% if request.GET.filter == 'skillset' %}
          <option value="skillset" selected>Skillset</option>
        {% else %}
          <option value="skillset">Skillset</option>
        {% endif %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default">
</form>

<ol style="padding-left: 15px">
    {% for consultant in object_list %}
        <li>
            <a href="{% url 'sogeti:detail' consultant.id %}">{{ consultant.first_name }}, {{ consultant.last_name }}</a> </br>
            Technology Group: {{ consultant.group }} </br>
            Primary Practice: {{ consultant.practices }}
            <hr style="margin-left: 0">
        </li> 
    {% empty %}
    No result match q=`<b>{{ request.GET.q }}</b>` & filter=`{{ request.GET.filter }}`
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
```